# Configuring Azure OpenAI Deployment Parameters to Match Public ChatGPT Settings

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

How can I configure the Azure OpenAI Deployment parameters, including past messages included, temperature, maximum response length, top-p value, frequency penalty, and presence penalty, to replicate the settings used in the public version of ChatGPT?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the exact details of the internal workings of ChatGPT are publicly available and looking through similar posts on the [Official OpenAI Community Forum](https://community.openai.com/), that does seem to be the case.

That being said, you should be able to get a fairly similar experience by maximizing temperature to allow the model to be creative in its response and playing with the system message to steer the response in the way it reponds.

The [Prompt Engineering Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/advanced-prompt-engineering) provide some good guidance on how you can author your system message to guide the model in how it gives responses.